# issues importing function in node/js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, passport.js, es6-modules

Hey I am having troubles importing the function "generateToken"

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

function generateToken(user) {
  // Generate and return jwt token
  const token = jwt.sign(({ user }), "secretKey", { expiresIn: "1h" });
  return token;
}

export { generateToken };
```

Here is my import `import { generateToken } from "../../server/jwtUtils.js"`

When I do this I get this error [image]

I have tried exporting the functions like this

```
module.exports = { generateToken
 }
```

And like this => `Export default generateToken`

When I do this I get this error => [image]

I actually don't know if this is an issue with my passport.js or node. Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do:

```js
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export function generateToken(user) {
  // Generate and return jwt token
  const token = jwt.sign(({ user }), "secretKey", { expiresIn: "1h" });
  return token;
};
```

Then:

```js
import {generateToken} from "./server/jwtUtils.js"; //< This needs to be a relative path to your file
const token = generateToken(user);
```

However, `export { generateToken };` is perfectly valid syntax in ES6 modules but typically done this way when exporting a list of things.

The `module.exports = { generateToken }` is CommonJS syntax and will not work with ES6 modules.